# compiling linux kernel for the beaglebone black using xenomai and buildroot

Tags: kernel, beagleboneblack, buildroot, xenomai

I am trying to build linux kernel "3.18.20" for the beaglebone black using xenomai "2.6.4" and buildroot "2015.08.1" to compile it.
I compile and run successful the kernel using the [patch-3.18.20-arm](http://xenomai.org/downloads/ipipe/v3.x/arm/ipipe-core-3.18.20-arm-6.patch) and the buildroot config

```
BR2_LINUX_KERNEL=y
BR2_LINUX_KERNEL_CUSTOM_VERSION=y
BR2_LINUX_KERNEL_CUSTOM_VERSION_VALUE="3.18.20"
BR2_LINUX_KERNEL_PATCH="~/beagleboneblack/linux-patches"
BR2_LINUX_KERNEL_DEFCONFIG="omap2plus"
BR2_LINUX_KERNEL_ZIMAGE=y
BR2_LINUX_KERNEL_DTS_SUPPORT=y
BR2_LINUX_KERNEL_INTREE_DTS_NAME="am335x-boneblack"

BR2_PACKAGE_XENOMAI=y
BR2_PACKAGE_XENOMAI_VERSION="2.6.4"
BR2_PACKAGE_XENOMAI_TESTSUITE=y
```

but when I run latency or xeno-test I get the following error:

```
Xenomai: /dev/rtheap is missing
(chardev, major=10 minor=254)
```

I used this version because it is the last stable version at the moment and [here](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.linux.real-time.xenomai.users/23303/match=beaglebone+black) said that The I-pipe patches are meant for mainline Linux kernels, not for Linux kernel forks

I am looking for a working kernel/patch version for beaglebone black and xenomai but I can't find it, can you point me in the right direction?

I find [this](http://brunosmartins.info/xenomai-on-the-beaglebone-black-in-14-easy-steps/) but they don't use the mainline kernel repository, they use [this](https://github.com/RobertCNelson/bb-kernel)

Comment: Check in the kernel log if xenomai is indeed started: dmesg | grep -i xeno

Comment: I get no output in dmesg, I haven't any module loaded and in the kernel-menuconfig there aren't any option tu enable xenomai support in the kernel or like a module

Comment: tried `# mknod /dev/rtheap c 10 254` ?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't enable the kernel part of Xenomai. You have to enable BR2_LINUX_KERNEL_EXT_XENOMAI in the "Linux kernel extensions" menu of the kernel.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more how this is done? I think a lot of people are like me, and patching linux for the first time.

Comment: You do 'make menuconfig' to configure Buildroot, you go to the Linux Kernel menu, you go to the Linux kernel externsions menu, and you select the Xenomai extension.

Answer (score -1):

You could use mainline Linux kernel as TI now supports it: http://www.ti.com/lsds/ti/tools-software/mainlinelinux_sw.page